# unable to get values from PER_ASSIGNMENT_SECURED_LIST_V table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, oracle-fusion-apps

I am working in oracle hcm fusion application. Writing a extract rule for a batch loader fast formula. in one of the extract rule formula i am using a DBI PER_HIST_ASG_ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER but it returning 0, that is no values in DBI. The problem is the DBI internally refer a secured view PER_ASSIGNMENT_SECURED_LIST_V. If I query this table from BI publisher I am not getting any rows. Some one suggest that Data role is missing. Can anyone tell me what is the exact datarole that I should add to acces the values from  that DBI.

Answer (score 0):

This View is based on security profile added in the Employment like BU,Department,Location etc.
So you try to retrieve the records from a Super User or Implementation user which is not attached any security profile, You will get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Data roles are configured differently for each organization that is using the Cloud.

So you have to check with your application security consultant for the exact data role you need for this table.